# Gradle error merging resources no admin priviledges

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get following error when i try to build my project with Gradle:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

I use command:

```
gradle build
```

I have Gradle dependency in build.gradle file for version 1.0.0. I first imported Eclipse project into Android studio and there were no problems while importing. Same stuff happens when i build from Android studio and from command prompt.

Anyone knows what might be problem?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you do **NOT** run as administrator to try to fix this. Any chance you're trying to work with a project that's located in a protected directory?

Comment: You were right, it works now, write down answer below so i could mark it as answer. I was running android studio with admin privileges and command prompt as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of elevation error has to do with requiring you to run as Administrator, which is something you generally don't want to do on Windows, certainly not all the time. Try running Android Studio as a non-Administrator user and try working with a project that's in a non-protected directory; e.g. your home directory is non-protected, but **Program Files** is protected.